# Multiple parameters in NSTimer selector

Tags: swift, nstimer

I would like to pass parameters to the following function through `userInfo`, because that function has to execute after delay.

```
func showAlert(alertTitle: String, withMessage alertMessage: String, fromController controller: UIViewController) {
     //do stuff...
}
```

Have already done that part with delay, but I do not know how to send multiple parameters to the body of `showAlert.`

```
func fireTimer() {
   timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("showAlert:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

---

I'm still getting errors, don't know why.

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

This is how my code looks like. What's wrong?

```
class AlertController: UIAlertController {  
var timer = NSTimer()

func showAlert(alertTitle: String, withMessage alertMessage: String, fromController controller: UIViewController)
{
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    controller.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func showAlert2(dict: [String: AnyObject])
{
    showAlert(dict["title"] as! String,
        withMessage: dict["message"] as! String,
        fromController: dict["controller"] as! UIViewController)
}

func fireTimer(title: String, message: String, viewController: UIViewController)
{
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("showAlert2:"), userInfo: ["title":title, "message": message, "controller": viewController], repeats: false)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot pass more than one parameter using NSTimer, however, you can make that parameter into an array or ditionary or similar.

Then create a new function that takes that array/dictionary and then calls your function with every parameter inside the array/dictionary

```
func fireTimer() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("showAlert2:"), userInfo: ["title":"a title", "message": "a message", "controller": controller], repeats: false)
}

func showAlert2(timer: NSTimer) {   
    let dict = timer.userInfo as NSDictionary

    showAlert(dict["title"] as String, wwithMessage: dict["message"] as String, fromController: dict["controller"] as UIViewController)
}

func showAlert(alertTitle: String, withMessage alertMessage: String, fromController controller: UIViewController) {
//    do stuff...
}
```

Comment: I've just added answer with error I get every time. Would be grateful if you could take a look at my code.

Comment: I ran your code and found the problem, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I dont know the whole process behind scheduleTimer but i totally forgot you have to have NSTimer as the parameter you're calling and then using the userInfo property of that passed timer.

Comment: For the task you're performing I would actually recommend using dispatch_after() instead so you dont have to deal with this "linker" function and just pass your parameters directly, but thats just my personal preference :)